# Odoo: how to create monthly recurring tasks that have the name or the number of the month in the description?

Tags: odoo, scheduled-tasks

In Odoo it is possible to create [recurring tasks](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/applications/services/project/tasks/recurring_tasks.html).
A recurring task is a task which instances automatically appear in the project after a given period elapses.

I would like to set a monthly recurring task in a way that each instance has the name or the number of the month in it.

For instance, I would like the recurring task "Check Invoice" would generate monthly tasks as "Check Invoice January", "Check Invoice February" an so on.

Do you know if it is possible to make Odoo do that? If yes, can you explain me how?

Comment: There are some ways to change name behaviour in Odoo, like overriding `display_name` or `name_get`, but in the end you need a date field on the tasks, to get the week from. I just scanned through Odoo16 recurring tasks code and didn't find a special date field set in recurring tasks, except for the `create_date`, which probably isn't the best fit for your requirement. So you have to decide on which date field base you want to "generate" the task name. A very easy example for changing name behaviour can be found in model `hr.contract.history` and a complex example on `product.product` (Odoo16).

Comment: @CZoellner, I hoped for an easier solution that could be used from the GUI, however thanks for the comment, it seems a good starting point.